# Uncompressing a Gzip format?

Tags: gzip, compression, inflate-exception

I am facing a problem with Gzip uncompressing.

The situation is like this. I have some text in UTF-8 format. Now this text is compressed using gzdeflate() function in PHP and then stored in a blob object in Mysql.

Now I tried to retrieve the blob object and then used Java's Gzip Stream to un compress it. But it throws an error saying that it is not in GZIP format.

I even used Inflater in Java to do the same but now I get "DataFormatException:incorrect header check". The code for the inflater is as below.

```
 //rs is the resultset
 //blobAsBytes is the byte array
 while(rs.next()){
        blob = rs.getBlob("old_text");
        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
        blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
    }

     Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
     decompresser.setInput(blobAsBytes);
     byte[] result = new byte[100];
     int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);  // this is the line where the exception is occurring.
     decompresser.end();

     // Decode the bytes into a String
     String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
     System.out.println(outputString);
```

I have to do this using Java and get all the text back that is stored in the database.

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gzencode()`, not `gzdeflate()`.  The latter does not produce the gzip format, it produces the deflate format.  The former *does* produce the gzip format.  The PHP functions are horribly and confusingly named.

Alternatively, use the `java.util.zip.Inflater` class with `nowrap` true in the `Inflater` constructor.  That will decode raw deflate data on the Java end.

Comment: OK that is interesting but here I have the data already compressed using gzdeflate() function and it is stored in the database.

Comment: OK that is interesting but here I have the data already compressed using gzdeflate() function and it is stored in the database. My requirement is to get the already stored data.  I tried with PHP's gzinflate() function and there it works just fine but when it comes to Java, its all failing to retrieve the data.